# I am not able to install meteor on ubuntu using curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, curl, meteor, openssl

Getting this every time when i am installing meteor using `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7821    0  7821    0     0   3988      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  3986
Downloading Meteor distribution
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to s3.amazonaws.com:443 

Retrying download in 5 seconds...
^[[D^[[A^[[C#=#=#                                                               curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to s3.amazonaws.com:443 

Retrying download in 5 seconds...
#=#=#                                                                         
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to s3.amazonaws.com:443 

Retrying download in 5 seconds...
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to s3.amazonaws.com:443 

Retrying download in 5 seconds...
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to s3.amazonaws.com:443 

Retrying download in 5 seconds...
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to s3.amazonaws.com:443 

Retrying download in 5 seconds...
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to s3.amazonaws.com:443 

Retrying download in 5 seconds...
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to s3.amazonaws.com:443 

Retrying download in 5 seconds...
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to s3.amazonaws.com:443 

Retrying download in 5 seconds...
```

Comment: Install where? What operating system are you using? Does you instance have internet connectivity?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu, ya i have internet connectivity

Comment: Which version exactly? 20.04?

Comment: I verified on Ubuntu 20.04 and the installation works perfectly fine. Whatever is happening must be due to your instance networking setup, such as no access to the internet.

Comment: @Marcin right, Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Are you in Iran?

Comment: Try to use the new installer, read here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/npm-packages/meteor-installer/README.md

Comment: Try the new way to install Meteor using NPM. 
`npm install -g meteor` 
https://www.meteor.com/developers/install

Comment: I tried this also but getting this error
EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/meteor/tmp-6407dNTkgZuSrVPN'

Comment: @Jankapunkt No I am in India

Comment: Okay I was just asking, because of geofencing but then it seems to be rather a local network issue. You may get better help with this opening an issue on GitHub I think